# get value part of specific word in AIX

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

want to search string and need part of string

file.txt:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE $$ENV$$_TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE, NO FALLBACK , 
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL, 
    NO AFTER JOURNAL, 
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT, 
    DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKADSRATIO
```

while using below `sed` command getting extra value

Output:

```
bash-4.3$ sed -n 's/.*$$ENV$$_//p' file.txt

**TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE** ,NO FALLBACK ,
```

I need only **`TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE`**

Comment: What can we use to find your string? What changes and what remains the same in your file? Presumably this is just an example, you don't just want `echo TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE`, so please [edit] your question and explain how we can recognize the relevant string. Will it always be whatever is after `$$ENV$$_` until the first comma? Will it always be on a line that starts with `CREATE`?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's/.*$$ENV$$_//p' example.txt
```

The command `s/pattern/replacement/` of `sed` searches all lines for the occurence of the regular expression `pattern` and replaces it. With the empty replacement, the pattern gets deleted, which seems to be what you want.

The trailing `p` outputs the modified line, while all default output is suppressed by the `-n` option.

Comment: Thanks for your response

when i try with below input as file getting extra value

-------------------------------------------
CREATE MULTISET TABLE $$ENV$$_TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKADSRATIO
_____________________________________

Output:
bash-4.3$ sed -n 's/.*$$ENV$$_//p' example1.txt
TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE ,NO FALLBACK ,
------------------------

I need only TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE

Comment: Re: your comment to Roman, `\$` (same for `\^`) is required to match a literal `$` even when not in anchoring position (which includes the end of the regexp but also with some implementations before a `\)`). [_A BRE special character has special properties in certain contexts. Outside those contexts, or when preceded by a  <backslash>, such a character is a BRE that matches the special character itself_](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03).

Comment: If not, it would be impossible to match a literal `^` at the start of a `\(...\)` as `\(\^...\)` would be undefined, and `\([^]...\)` would not work.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep` when built with (recent) PCRE support (as is common on GNU and BSD systems):

```
grep -Po '\Q$$ENV$$_\E\K[^\s,]+' < file
```

would extract all the sequences of characters other than whitespace and comma that follow every occurrence of `$$ENV$$_`.

If GNU `grep` is not available, the same thing can be done with `perl` (the `P` in PCRE):

```
perl -lne 'print for /\$\$ENV\$\$_\K[^\s,]+/g' < file
```

Or if the `perl` version is too old to support `\K`:

```
perl -lne 'print for /\$\$ENV\$\$_([^\s,]+)/g' < file
```

Comment: am using AIX and getting below error 

grep: Not a recognized flag: P
grep: Not a recognized flag: o
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L]  [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...]

Comment: @Baranidharan, yes you do need the GNU implementation of `grep`. See edit for alternatives. The second one at least should work on AIX

Answer (score 1):

**`sed`** approach:

```
sed -n 's/^CREATE.*$_\([^[:space:],]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

- `\([^[:space:],]*\)` - the 1st captured group containing characters except whitespace(s) `[:space:]` and comma `,`

---

The output:

```
TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/.*$$ENV$$_/!d;s///;s/,.*//'
```

- `/.*$$ENV$$_/!d`: If the line doesn't contain `$$ENV$$_`, no output, no further processing
- `s///`: remove the matching pattern
- `s/,.*//`: remove the comma and everything after

Comment: can you please provide command to get only EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE, means remove string before . in output

Out Put: TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE

Comment: Simply exchange `.*$$ENV$$_` with `.*$$ENV$$_TEMP_ESM.`

Comment: am getting extra space in the sting output, how to i cut down the extra sapce

Comment: Where is that extra space? At the end? Not for the given example. Maybe there can be a space before the comma? Then use `s/ *,.*//` As the last command.